# What is the running time of two sorting algorithms if one is merge sort and one is insertion sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, pseudocode, mergesort

If I have to sort one list and merge it with another already sorted one. Then what will the running time be if I use merge sort and insertion sort? 
Merge sort is: n logn 
Insertion sort is: n^2
But together they are?

EDIT: Oh, so what I actually meant was that I had to sort one of the lists and merge them together.
I have made the pseudocode for the insertion sort, but I don't know what the running time of the two algorithms will be.
http://gyazo.com/0010f053f0fe64a82dad1dd383740a3f

Comment: I don't think merge sort applies here. "merge" and "merge sort" are two different things.

Comment: Please provide some pseudocode of what you're trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexity of merging two sorted lists with lengths **n1** and **n2** is **O(n1 + n2)**; that should be enough to work out the big-Oh of the entire algorithm

Comment: I understand it now. Thanks!
My problem was that I didn't understand how the running time of insertion sort and merging could be O(n+m^2) :). Thanks!